# Why Does Using a Variable for the Index Work in This Selection Sort Algorithm in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, selection-sort

I'm trying to understand why using a variable to assign the index works fine, instead of directly using the index itself in the following code snippet of the selection sort algorithm using `JavaScript`.

**What I Tried:**
I attempted to use the index of the minimum element directly (j):

```
let myArray = [7, 9, 4, 16, 2, 0, 4, -18];

function selectionSortAlgorithm(anArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < anArray.length - 1; i++) {
        let min = anArray[i];

        for (let j = i + 1; j < anArray.length; j++) {
            if (min > anArray[j]) {
                min = anArray[j];
            }
        }
        let temp = anArray[i];
        anArray[i] = min;
        anArray[j] = temp;
    }
    return anArray;
}

console.log(selectionSortAlgorithm(myArray));
```

**The Correct Code:**
I found that using a new variable for the minimum element (minIndex) corrects the issue:

```
let myArray = [7, 9, 4, 16, 2, 0, 4, -18];

function selectionSortAlgorithm(anArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < anArray.length - 1; i++) {
        let min = anArray[i];
        let minIndex = i;

        for (let j = i + 1; j < anArray.length; j++) {
            if (min > anArray[j]) {
                min = anArray[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        let temp = anArray[i];
        anArray[i] = min;
        anArray[minIndex] = temp;
    }
    return anArray;
}

console.log(selectionSortAlgorithm(myArray));
```

Comment: What makes you think that `j` would contain the index of the Min element?

Comment: The index `j` in the inner loop of the first attempt is not the index of the minimum value. `j` is always `anArray.length` when that loop terminates. It finds the minimum value but forgets the index where it's found.

Comment: If you put `console.log(j);` in the first version and `console.log(minIndex)` in the second version, you'll see the difference.

Comment: That's in the point ! Many thanks, now i understand the logic (taking the index of the min element when the condition is true) and not j, which is always will be the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your first code is that `j` is declared inside of `for` statement.

```js
for (let j = i + 1; j < anArray.length; j++) {
  if (min > anArray[j]) {
    min = anArray[j];
  }
}
```

So when you try to access it out of the statement, it isn't accessible

```
ReferenceError: j is not define
```

In the second example, you create `let minIndex` outside of the `for` statement. That's why you can access it.

Comment: yes it's true, and also as @aztecCodes said, j is not always the index of the min element
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Credit to @AztecCodes**

What makes you think that j would contain the index of the Min element? –

The index j in the inner loop of the first attempt is not the index of the minimum value. j is always anArray.length when that loop terminates. It finds the minimum value but forgets the index where it's found.

If you put console.log(j); in the first version and console.log(minIndex) in the second version, you'll see the difference.